# How to extract time from string in python using pattern matching?

Tags: python, regex

An example of the python string is `'8:30 AM- 10:00 PM Subject: Math'`. In general, the string contains a start time, end time, and the subject I want to separate this string into 3 components: the start time, end time, and subject. For example `8:30 AM`, `10:00 PM`, and `Subject: Math`.

How can I do this using regex in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) using a *positive lookbehind* to `AM` or `PM` having an optional `-` and a space character as a delimiter:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = "8:30 AM- 10:00 PM Subject: Math"
>>> re.split(r"(?<=AM|PM)-?\s", s)
['8:30 AM', '10:00 PM', 'Subject: Math']
```